# Android Studio: Cannot find the 'design view' section after updating to ver. 3.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated Android Studio to version 3.5.1, and now I cannot find 'design view' section which used to be under the activity_main.xml tab. I would like really like some on this one, as I am totally new to Android Studio. I have posted a screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are various reasons for Design view to fail to render layouts.**

You can try the following:

1. Make sure XML representation of layout is error free.
2. Try changing the API levels in the design views.
3. Clean build your project by going to `Build > Clean build`
4. Ensure you don’t have any file from SDK that is missing
5. If everything is proper still if android studio is
   not able to render your layout invalidate cache and restart android
   studio by going to `File > Invalidate Cache/Restart`

I know I have mentioned too many steps but since there isn’t a description for your question and its little hard to determine the exact reason why it happens.

Comment: You were correct! There was an error in my XML representation, I corrected it, and now it works fine! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows OS there is a key combination to show the designer, you should press at the same time:

```
    Alt + Shift + Right arrow (or Left arrow)
```

Comment: That's weird, ok try something else. Go to File menu and click on Invalidate Caches, it will show to you a confirmation dialog. Click on Invalidate and Restart and wait until the Android SDK open and build your project. Keep me updated !

Answer (score 0):

**You can find it here**

Go to View->Tool Windows->Preview

[image]